# Laravel 4 show table status statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I'm having trouble running a `SHOW` query using laravel, current attempts:

```
 $status = DB::statement('SHOW TABLE status FROM yqueue LIKE ' . $table_name);

 $status = DB::statement('SHOW TABLE status LIKE ' . $table_name);
```

I have also tried to use `unprepared` but same issue;

```
$status =  DB::unprepared('SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM testdb like ' . $table_name);
```

I haven't been able to find any example of`SHOW` being used in Laravel.

the error:

```
 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
```

What I'm doing wrong?,  any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `DB::select();`
may be this can help your problem, or using eloquent models

Comment: unable to use models for these tables since they will be created on user request. as for the select, I really can't see how I can use it for the `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me.

```
DB::select("show table status");
```

Thanks to @Arryangga Aliev Pratama